# Unity crossdomain.xml

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crossdomain.xml

I'm getting error messages regarding the crossdomain.xml file and I don't know how to resolve it. I have no trouble accessing the URL from a web browser.

From web browser

```
http://192.168.1.116:80/locJSON.txt
```

gives me back a big snippet of JSON nicely

From web browser

```
http://192.168.1.116/crossdomain.xml
```

gives me back the crossdomain information

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"  to-ports="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
```

But from within Unity, if I try the following code I get issues.

```
private void QueryAIServer()
{
    string url = "http://192.168.1.116/locJSON.txt";
    WWW AIServer = new WWW(url);

    while(!AIServer.isDone) { };

    Debug.Log("Connected to AI Server!");
}
```

When I get past the while line, if I inspect inside the AIServer variable in the debugger, I can see the message "System.Security.SecurityException: No valid crossdomain policy available to allow access" drawn in red for AIServer.bytes, AIServer.data, and AIServer.text

Also, I do get the following messages output in the console. Any insight would be appreciated.

> UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
>
> MonoForks.System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString, Boolean dontEscape) MonoForks.System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) MonoForks.System.Uri:.ctor (string) MonoForks.System.Windows.Interop.PluginHost.get_SourceUri () MonoForks.System.Windows.Browser.Net.CrossDomainPolicyManager.GetCachedWebPolicy (MonoForks.System.Uri uri) UnityEngine.UnityCrossDomainHelper.GetSecurityPolicy (System.String requesturi_string, IPolicyProvider policyProvider) UnityEngine.UnityCrossDomainHelper.GetSecurityPolicy (System.String requesturi_string) UnityEngine.WWW:get_isDone() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:556) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

```
You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading. Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found UnityEngine.WWW:get_assetBundle() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:559) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

Unable to determine the audio type from the URL (http://192.168.1.116/locJSON.txt) . Please specify the type. UnityEngine.WWW:get_audioClip() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:559) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

Streaming of 'ogg' on this platform is not supported UnityEngine.WWW:get_oggVorbis() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:559) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading. Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found UnityEngine.WWW:get_size() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:559) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading. Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found UnityEngine.WWW:get_texture() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:559) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading. Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found UnityEngine.WWW:get_textureNonReadable() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:559) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

Unable to determine the audio type from the URL (http://192.168.1.116/locJSON.txt) . Please specify the type. UnityEngine.WWW:get_audioClip() PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:559) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)

Connected to AI Server! UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) PlayEditorMain:QuerryAIServer() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:558) PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs:262) MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Buttons/MainMenuButton.cs:23) UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions) UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:765) UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1435) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1063) UICamera:Update() (at Assets/3rd Party/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:909)
```

Comment: hey did you get the answer i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has gotten me on this multiple times is not saving it as UTF-8 encoded. Some editors do this if you've opened it in say notepad and re-saved it after making changes. Notepad (at least the version in Windows 8.1) has a select box for checking the encoding type you want to use when saving and it defaults to ANSI.

Edit: 
One thing I want to make sure - and I'm sure you just omitted it, but just for the sake of clarity, the tags in the crossdomain need to be surrounded by `<cross-domain-policy></cross-domain-policy>` and the very first element as with all XML files needs to be `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`  In total..

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"  to-ports="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: This is the file
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"  to-ports="*"/>
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>`

Comment: I haven't used many of the element types you're using in this file, but it is worth asking does a simpler version of the file work - such as `<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>`

Comment: your simpler file produced the same results.

Comment: @Dalanchoo did you find the answer ? please post answer of your question i am almost getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this standard allow all crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>

   <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```